# Get index position of an alphabet

Tags: javascript, java

In java we can get the index position of an alphabet using below code :

```
int idx = s.charAt(i) - 97;
```

Now I am looking for similar code in JavaScript:

```
var idx = s.charAt(i) - 97;
```

But in javascript I getting `isNaN` error message; What is the correct way to do this.

Comment: ```var a="javascripit"; console.log(a[<index>]);``` This works

Comment: Don't use "magic numbers" like "97".Use 'a' instead. Also, be aware that while this works in Java, it may not work in other languages. For example, in C there is no guarantee that the letters of the alphabet are in exact sequential order

Comment: This will not work for unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

```
"a".charCodeAt(0) - 97
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the case of the letter try:

```
var idx = s.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i) - 97;
```

If you care about the case you can try

```
var idx = s.charCodeAt(i) - 97;
```

But for capital letters this will result in negative numbers. The second option is the one which has the same behavior as the Java sample you provided.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
int idx = s.charAt(i) - 96;
```

***Note 96, not 97.***

Reference Link: https://dev.to/bladesensei/get-alphabet-position-value-of-a-letter-javascript-70p

Answer (score 0):

Whether to subtract the code unit by 96 or 97 depends on the context.

If you don't want to remember whether the magic number is 96 or 97, let's use the first letter in the alphabet ("a") as the anchor and find the offset of your target letter from that anchor.

```js
const example = "abcdefg"
const anchor = "a".charCodeAt(0)
for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  const index = example.charCodeAt(i) - anchor
  console.log(`Letter ${example[i]} is at index ${index} in the alphabet`)
}
```

If you want to use one-based index, add 1 after each calculation.

```
const index = example.charCodeAt(i) - "a".charCodeAt(0) + 1
```